# Micro-components architecture with python / Django / Drf

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, wercker

I have several applications in my Django project:

```
- ticker
- payments
- crypto
- referrals
- core
```

I am using `Docker` wrapped by `Wercker` (quite limiting I would say, but saves time).

My question is, how to deploy each application as a standalone container as a start, and a standalone VPS Node in the private network later.

Also, I would really like to deploy the `postgres` instance into a separate instance in the private network and not just a container.

My logic tells me that a separate Django project will be required for this purpose.

We have a little bit of a weird workflow there... writing a `docker-compose` file during a `wercker` step and then triggering it in the `ENTRYPOINT`.

I am attaching my `docker-compose` and `wercker.yml` file.

`docker-compose`:

```
version: '2'
services:
    postgis:
        image: mdillon/postgis
        environment:
           POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_USER}
           POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
           POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_DB}
        volumes:
            - /nexchange/database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        restart: always
    app:
        image: onitsoft/nexchange:${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}
        volumes:
            - /nexchange/mediafiles:/usr/share/nginx/html/media
            - /nexchange/staticfiles:/usr/share/nginx/html/static
        links:
            - postgis
        restart: always
    web:
        image: onitsoft/nginx
        volumes:
            - /nexchange/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
            - /nexchange/etc/nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
            - /nexchange/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - /nexchange/mediafiles:/usr/share/nginx/html/media
            - /nexchange/staticfiles:/usr/share/nginx/html/static
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"            
        links:
            - app
        restart: always
```

`wercker.yml`:

```
box: pitervergara/geodjango:nexchange
ports:
  - "8000"

dev:
  services:
   - id: mdillon/postgis
     env:
       POSTGRES_USER: nexchange
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD: nexchange
       POSTGRES_DB: nexchange
  steps:
    - script:
        name: export django settings module
        code: |
          export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=nexchange.settings_dev
    - script:
        name: create static and media root
        code: |
          mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html/static
          mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html/media
    - npm-install
    - maxon/npm-run:
        script: bower
    - maxon/npm-run:
        script: build-js
    - script:
        name: pip install requirements (with cache)
        code: |
          pip_download_cache="$WERCKER_CACHE_DIR/wercker/_pipcache"
          mkdir -p ${pip_download_cache}
          pip install --cache-dir ${pip_download_cache} -r requirements.txt
          has_krakenex=$(python -c "import importlib; k = importlib.find_loader('krakenex'); print(str(k is not None))")
          if [ "${has_krakenex}" == "False" ]; then
            git clone https://github.com/onitsoft/python3-krakenex.git /usr/src/krakenex
            cd /usr/src/krakenex
            python3 setup.py install
            cd -
          fi
          python -c "import krakenex; print('import krakenex sucessfully executed')"
    - script:
        name: Django make migrations
        code: |
          cat <(echo "yes") - | python manage.py makemigrations
    - script:
        name: wait...
        code: |
          sleep 5
    - script:
        name: Django apply migrations
        code: |
          python manage.py migrate
    - script:
        name: Django compile messages
        code: |
          # python manage.py compilemessages
    - script:
      name: Django create superuser
      code: |
          echo "from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.create_superuser('onit', 'weare@init.ws','weare0nit')" | python manage.py shell
    - script:
        name: Django import Currency fixture
        code: |
          python manage.py loaddata core/fixtures/currency.json
    - script:
        name: Django import Payment Methods fixture
        code: |
          python manage.py loaddata core/fixtures/payment_method.json
    - script:
        name: Django import Payment Preference fixture
        code: |
          python manage.py loaddata core/fixtures/payment_preference.json
    - script:
        name: Django import Withdraw address fixture
        code: |
          python manage.py loaddata core/fixtures/withdraw_address.json
    - script:
        name: Django import affiliate program fixture
        code: |
          python manage.py loaddata core/fixtures/affiliate_program.json
    - script:
        name: Django run ticker update prices command
        code: |
          python manage.py ticker
    - script:
        name: Django collect static
        code: |
          python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
    - script:
        name: Link pre-commit hook script
        code: |     
          chmod +x .pre-commit.sh 
          cd .git/hooks/
          ln -fs ../../.pre-commit.sh pre-commit
          cd -
    - create-file:
        name: Create cron invoked script to run ticker
        filename: /ticker.sh
        overwrite: true
        content: |-
          #!/bin/bash
          #
          export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=${DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE}
          export POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_USER}
          export POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
          export POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_DB}
          export POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=${POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR}
          export POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=${POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT}
          #
          cd ${WERCKER_SOURCE_DIR}
          /usr/local/bin/python manage.py ticker >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
    - script:
        name: Add cron job
        code: |
          chmod +x /ticker.sh
          echo "* * * * * root /ticker.sh" > /etc/crontab
          cron
    - internal/watch:
        code: |
          echo 'Dev server running'
           npm run watch-js & newrelic-admin run-program  python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        reload: false

build:
  services:
   - id: mdillon/postgis
     env:
       POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_USER}
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
       POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_DB}
  steps:
    - install-packages:
      packages: netcat
    - script:
        name: create static and media root
        code: |
          mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html/static
          mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html/media
    - script:
      name: Install node requirements
      code: |
        # https://github.com/wercker/support/issues/227 :(
        rm -fr node_modules && npm install --production
    - maxon/npm-run:
        script: bower-prd
    - script:
        name: Install python requirements
        code: |
          pip_download_cache="$WERCKER_CACHE_DIR/wercker/_pipcache"
          mkdir -p ${pip_download_cache}
          pip install --cache-dir ${pip_download_cache} -r requirements.txt
          has_krakenex=$(python -c "import importlib; k = importlib.find_loader('krakenex'); print(str(k is not None))")
          if [ "${has_krakenex}" == "False" ]; then
            git clone https://github.com/onitsoft/python3-krakenex.git /usr/src/krakenex
            cd /usr/src/krakenex
            python3 setup.py install
            cd -
          fi
          python -c "import krakenex; print('import krakenex sucessfully executed')"
    - script:
        name: Django migrations
        code: |
          python manage.py makemigrations
    - script:
        name: django collect and compile translations
        code: |
          # python manage.py compilemessages
    - script:
        name: Django collect static
        code: |
          python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
    - script:
      name: copy files
      code: |
        mkdir -p /usr/src/app
        cp -r [a-z]* /usr/src/app
        cp -r /usr/share/nginx/html/static $WERCKER_OUTPUT_DIR/staticfiles
        cp -r /usr/share/nginx/html/media $WERCKER_OUTPUT_DIR/mediafiles
    - script:
        name: place docker-compose and nginx.conf files
        code: |
          mv "nginx.conf" "$WERCKER_OUTPUT_DIR/nginx.conf"
          mv "docker-compose.yml" "$WERCKER_OUTPUT_DIR/docker-compose.yml"
    - create-file:
        #
        # PEM_FILE_CONTENT - the key to SSH into server (create key par via wercker web interface. remeber to install public key on server)
        # SSH_USER - the user to SSH into server
        # DEST_HOST_ADDR - server where to deploy  
        #
        # DOCKER_HUB_USER - dockerhub username
        # DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD - dockerhub password (defined as a protectd var)
        # DOCKER_HUB_REPO - the dockerhub repo where to push (repo must already exists and should be private)
        name: Create production entrypoint
        filename: /entrypoint.sh
        overwrite: true
        content: |-
          #!/bin/bash
          # ###
          # This script is generate in deploy step and:
          #   Exports variables
          #   Apply migrations
          #   Starts gunicorn
          # ###
          export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=${DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE}
          export GUNICORN_PORT=${GUNICORN_PORT}
          export POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_USER}
          export POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
          export POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_DB}
          export POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=${POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR}
          export POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=${POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT}
          export NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=${NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE}
          export NEW_RELIC_ENVIRONMENT=${NEW_RELIC_ENVIRONMENT}
          export NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY=${NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY}
          #
          while ! nc -z ${POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR} ${POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT}
          do
            >&2 echo "PostgreSQL '(${POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR}:${POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT})' not ready - waiting..."
            sleep 1;
          done
          echo "PostgreSQL '(${POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR}:${POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT})' is ready - moving on..."
          #
          # Apply migrations
          python /usr/src/app/manage.py migrate
          # Import fixtures
          python /usr/src/app/manage.py loaddata core/fixtures/currency.json
          python /usr/src/app/manage.py loaddata core/fixtures/payment_method.json
          python /usr/src/app/manage.py loaddata core/fixtures/affiliate_program.json
          echo "To load the 'withdraw_address' fixture, uncomment the next line"
          # python manage.py loaddata core/fixtures/withdraw_address.json
          #
          # Prepare log files and start outputting logs to stdout
          # adapted from 
          # http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2015/04/19/packaging-django-applications-as-docker-container-images/
          touch /var/log/gunicorn_error.log
          touch /var/log/gunicorn_access.log
          tail -n 0 -f /var/log/*.log &
          # Copy static data to nginx volume
          cp -ra $WERCKER_OUTPUT_DIR/staticfiles/* /usr/share/nginx/html/static
          cp -ra $WERCKER_OUTPUT_DIR/mediafiles/* /usr/share/nginx/html/media
          #
          # Create superuser
          echo "from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.create_superuser('onit', 'weare@onit.ws','weare0nit')" | python manage.py shell
          #
          # Start Cron Process
          cron
          echo "Gunicorn start"
          exec newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn --chdir /usr/src/app --name nexchange --bind 0.0.0.0:${GUNICORN_PORT} --workers 3 --log-level=info --log-file=/var/log/gunicorn_error.log --access-logfile=/var/log/gunicorn_access.log nexchange.wsgi:application "$@"
    - script:
        name: set entrypoint as executable
        code: |
          chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
    - create-file:
        name: Create cron invoked script to run ticker
        filename: /ticker.sh
        overwrite: true
        content: |-
          #!/bin/bash
          #
          export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=${DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE}
          export POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_USER}
          export POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
          export POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_DB}
          export POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=${POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR}
          export POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=${POSTGIS_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT}
          #
          cd ${WERCKER_SOURCE_DIR}
          /usr/local/bin/python manage.py ticker >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
    - script:
        name: Add cron job
        code: |
          chmod +x /ticker.sh
          echo "* * * * * root /ticker.sh" > /etc/crontab
    - script:
        name: echo python information
        code: |
          echo "python version $(python --version) running"
          echo "pip version $(pip --version) running"
          echo "installed python packages:"
          echo "$(pip freeze | sort)"
    - internal/docker-push:
        username: $DOCKER_HUB_USER
        password: $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
        tag: ${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}
        repository: $DOCKER_HUB_REPO
        registry: https://registry.hub.docker.com
        entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh
        ports: ${GUNICORN_PORT}
        working-dir: /usr/src/app

deploy:
  box: pcfseceng/ci-ssh-client
  steps:
    - mktemp:
        envvar: PRIVATEKEY_PATH
    - create-file:
        name: write key
        filename: $PRIVATEKEY_PATH
        content: $PEM_FILE_CONTENT_PRIVATE  
        overwrite: true
    - script:
      name: Do deploy
      code: |
        SSH_OPTIONS="-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $PRIVATEKEY_PATH"
        SSH_DEST="$SSH_USER@$DEST_HOST_ADDR"
        SUBSTR=${WERCKER_GIT_COMMIT:0:9}
        scp ${SSH_OPTIONS} nginx.conf ${SSH_DEST}:/nexchange/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        scp ${SSH_OPTIONS} docker-compose.yml ${SSH_DEST}:/nexchange/docker-compose.yml
        ssh ${SSH_OPTIONS} ${SSH_DEST} << EOF
          # export the variables that docker-compose will inject into DB container
          export POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_USER}
          export POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
          export POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_DB}
          export DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG=${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}
          echo "Printing current env:"
          /usr/bin/env
          echo "env of env"
          # Login to docker hub (for private images)
          sudo docker login \
            -u $DOCKER_HUB_USER \
            -p $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
          # Start new instance
          sudo -E docker-compose -f /nexchange/docker-compose.yml pull
          sudo -E docker-compose -f /nexchange/docker-compose.yml up -d
        EOF

tests:
  steps:
    - script:
        name: export django settings
        code: |
          export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=nexchange.settings_test
    - script:
        name: Install python requirements
        code: |
          pip_download_cache="$WERCKER_CACHE_DIR/wercker/_pipcache"
          mkdir -p ${pip_download_cache}
          pip install --cache-dir ${pip_download_cache} -r requirements.txt
          has_krakenex=$(python -c "import importlib; k = importlib.find_loader('krakenex'); print(str(k is not None))")
          if [ "${has_krakenex}" == "False" ]; then
            git clone https://github.com/onitsoft/python3-krakenex.git /usr/src/krakenex
            cd /usr/src/krakenex
            python3 setup.py install
            cd -
          fi
          python -c "import krakenex; print('import krakenex sucessfully executed')"
    - script:
      name: Install node requirements
      code: |
        # rm -fr node_modules && npm install
        npm install
    - maxon/npm-run:
        script: bower
    - script:
        name: Backend tests
        code: |
          coverage erase
          coverage run --source="." manage.py test -v 3
          coverage report
          coverage html -d cover
    - script:
        name: Frontend tests
        code: |
          # export PHANTOMJS_BIN=${WERCKER_SOURCE_DIR}/node_modules/.bin/phantomjs
          # npm run-script test
    - script:
        name: Validate New Relic config file
        code: |
          newrelic-admin validate-config ${NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE}
    - script:
        name: Install Phantomjs tests frontend
        code: |
          #cd /usr/local/share
          #sudo wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
          #sudo tar xfj phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
          #sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/share/phantomjs
          #sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
          #sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs

    - script:
        name: Test_selenium
        code: |
          cd /pipeline/source
#          python manage.py test_selenium

static-validation:
  steps:
    - script:
        name: Run static-validation.sh
        code: |
          bash static-validation.sh
```

Comment: could you be more clear about the question? i dont get it.

Comment: Well I would like the deploy targets to be spread across several machines, more over i would like to have inner Django apps in separate containers / nodes

Answer (score -1):

You can update the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in the `settings.py` file using the startup script. This startup script will be called using the `Entrypoint`.

Then you can pass parameter to container start command based on which the startup script will decide which app needs to added to the `settings.py` file.